# Criar controles de forma dinâmica no WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

Preciso criar checklists que dependem de entradas e processamentos anteriores. Como faço para criar estes "checklists" de forma dinâmica no WPF? (um trecho de código, por favor).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CheckBox ch1 = new CheckBox();
ch1.Location = new Point(10, 10);
ch1.Text = "Olá Mundo!";
this.Controls.Add(ch1);
```

Vê se resolve, insira também suas opções default, como por exemplo se quer que ele venha checado já, etc.

Comment: Eu não estou achando um método que se encaixe com `this.Controls.Add(ch1)`

Comment: this é o nome do formulário que você está, ai no caso a linha adiciona o componente nesse formulário.Aparece que erro?

Comment: A classe Controls não está disponível apartir de "this" (já havia lido algo semelhante em outro tópico, mas acho que essa classe é apenas do windows forms).

Comment: tente adicionar um panel e adicionar dentro dele
panelnome.Children.Add(ch1);

Comment: Ok. Funcionou. Espero que o panel se expanda conforme o número de checklists.

Comment: qualquer coisa comenta ai que a gente tenta resolver ^^